# Cassandra fails due to access violation exception on Windows 10

Tags: java, cassandra, access-violation, cassandra-3.0

I was working on my project that uses **Cassandra** and **Redis** as databases when I needed to reinstall Windows. On previous installation of Windows everything worked with Cassandra but now when I have **latest Java** and `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME` set up. I have Cassandra 3.11.1 unpacked and ready to go but when I try to start a server I get:

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0x0000005) error that has been encountered by Java Runtime Environment.

I have read that this was merely a memory problem when I looked up starting parameters for JRE that was blank so I set the parameters as `-Xmx2048m`.

Comment: Do not use the latest versions of java.. use 8u_151 or 8u_152. Check the installation with that java environment

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Using latest **Java 8 instead of 9** fixed it. Specifically I have `JAVA_HOME` pointing to `jdk1.8.0_171` instead of `jdk-9.0.4`.

Comment: I didn't try this lately can anybody confirm that this issue is resolved for Java 9? Thank you.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Java 8 and still get this exception.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Java  8 and still facing this.

Comment: @OmarRabee the problem might have arised in specific java 8 version, i.e. minor and patch versions may play a role